# Choosing a frame-rate for an animation project

Tags: recommendation, after-effects

How do you choose a framerate for an animation project? In this case I know the exact context where the video will be displayed (company's head office, on a 51" HD TV) and it needs to look  really slick.

Comment: I will write a simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have specified the output device, a 51" HDTV but I don't know what camera, animation software, or video editing gear you plan to use.

Here are the standard video frame rates for HDTV as quoted from this WIKI page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-definition_television

Standard frame or field rates

ATSC table 3 defines the following frame rates for digital high-definition television.[24]

```
23.976 Hz (film-looking frame rate compatible with NTSC clock speed standards)
24 Hz (international film and ATSC high-definition material)
25 Hz (PAL, SECAM film, standard-definition, and high-definition material)
29.97 Hz (NTSC standard-definition material)
59.94 Hz (ATSC high-definition material)
60 Hz (ATSC high-definition material)
```

The optimum format for a broadcast depends upon the type of videographic recording medium used and the image's characteristics. For best fidelity to the source the transmitted field ratio, lines, and frame rate should match those of the source.

Although PAL, SECAM and NTSC frame rates technically apply only to standard definition television, not HD, with the roll out of HD, countries maintained the heritage of their former systems. HDTV in former PAL countries operates at a frame rate of 50 Hz and HDTV in former NTSC countries operates at 60 Hz.[25]

How to choose?

First identify the process by which you are going to animate your subject. Is it software or a stop action camera or both or something else.

Next, you want to learn what are the compatible frame rates and formats across all the animation tools you are using in your workflow.

Next, select the highest resolution and frame rate that is compatible with all your gear.

Next, make a short sample and then test it on a close if not same model HDTV that is in the "company's head office."

Comment: Sorry, I thought the After Effects tag made it clear that is the program I was talking about. Anyway, the whole animation will be created within After Effects with static elements drawn in Illustrator, no actual camera work.

Comment: So then determine if you are NTSC or PAL, and set your project to 1920 x 1080 progressive. BTW: the tag was implicit, I wanted something more explicit.